# Parse JSON to POJO when data type of value for same key changes

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have below `JSON`

```
{      
    "date":{
        "year":2017,
        "month":3,
        "day":12
    },
    "name":"Jon",
    "message":{
        "product":"orange",
        "price":2000
    }
}
```

and sometimes it comes as below `JSON`:

```
 {      
   "date":2017312,
    "name":"Jon",
    "message":{
        "product":"orange",
        "price":2000
    }
  }
```

Notice that the date can be `JSON object` or `long` value. How can I parse this to `POJO`? I am using `Jackson` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### LocalDate

You need to implement custom deserialiser and annotate given field with `JsonDeserialize` annotation. For below `POJO` model:

```
class Pojo {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateJsonDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate date;
    private String name;
    private Message message;

    // getters, setters
}

class Message {

    private String product;
    private int price;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Simple deserialiser implementation could look like this:

```
class LocalDateJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            MapType mapType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Integer.class);
            JsonDeserializer<Object> mapDeserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(mapType);
            Map<String, Integer> date = (Map<String, Integer>) mapDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);

            return LocalDate.of(date.get("year"), date.get("month"), date.get("day"));
        } else if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
            // You need to be really careful here. Date format is ambiguous
            // You should test it for all months and days
            String date = p.getValueAsString();
            int year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 4));
            // much better to use always two digits for month: `03` instead `3`
            int month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(4, 5));
            int day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(5, 7));

            return LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        } else if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json1 = "json 1 ...";
        String json2 = "json 2....";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json1, Pojo.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, Pojo.class));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Pojo{date=2017-03-12, name='Jon', message=Message{product='orange', price=2000}}
Pojo{date=2017-03-12, name='Jon', message=Message{product='orange', price=2000}}
```

Of course you need to handle all corner cases and improve error handling but generally this how we should treat values which could have different formats: `JSON object`, `JSON array`, `primitives`.

### LocalDateTime

For `LocalDateTime` it should look int the similar way. We need to create `POJO` model:

```
class Pojo {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeJsonDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime time;
    private String name;
    private Message message;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Custom deserialiser could look like below:

```
class LocalDateTimeJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            MapType mapType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
            JsonDeserializer<Object> mapDeserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(mapType);
            Map<String, Object> node = (Map<String, Object>) mapDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
            Map<String, Integer> date = (Map<String, Integer>) node.get("date");
            Map<String, Integer> time = (Map<String, Integer>) node.get("time");

            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(date.get("year"), date.get("month"), date.get("day"));
            LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(time.get("hour"), time.get("minute"), time.get("second"), time.get("nano"));

            return LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime);
        } else if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
            // You need to be really careful here. Date format is ambiguous
            // You should test it for all months and days
            String date = p.getValueAsString();
            // parse date string
            // ...

            return LocalDateTime.now();
        } else if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Deserialising example looks the same as for `LocalDate`. For below `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "time": {
    "date": {
      "year": 2019,
      "month": 3,
      "day": 29
    },
    "time": {
      "hour": 13,
      "minute": 21,
      "second": 20,
      "nano": 620000000
    }
  },
  "name": "Jon",
  "message": {
    "product": "orange",
    "price": 2000
  }
}
```

it should print:

```
Pojo{time=2019-03-29T13:21:20.620, name='Jon', message=Message{product='orange', price=2000}}
```

Also, take a look on [`JavaTimeModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) module which covers all `java.time.*` classes and allow to serialise and deserialise in a standard way,

Comment: It is giving me time values but all other values are coming as null.

Comment: @user812142, what is a `JSON` payload? I tested it for these two in questions and it works.

Comment: sorry it worked. I modified it for LocalDateTime but that is not working. Can you help me how can i modify this code for {"time":{"date":{"year":2019,"month":3,"day":29},"time":{"hour":13,"minute":21,"second":20,"nano":620000000}}

Comment: @user812142, what do you mean by modify it for `LocalDateTime`? Do you have two `POJO` classes and in one you have `LocalDateTime` data and in other `LocalDate`? Or you have one class and you want to deserialise all these 3 different `JSON` payloads to the same class?

Comment: I have two POJO classes and in one i have LocalDateTime data and in other LocalDate

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by using a custom desrializer where you can logically check the field.(e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson)

May be the field length can be the logic used to parse it into consituents here.

Comment: is it possible to get JSONObjet and long value as a text and then get their length?